# What is the maximum amount of gravity a humanoid species can evolve under?

Tags: evolution, gravity

Just as it says in the title, what is the maximum amount of gravity a humanoid species with the same intelligence as a human can evolve under? 2G,4G,6G? I know they would be shorter but will they also be more muscular?

Comment: Suggest looking at the square-cube law of scaling, and the largest ape-like creatures we know about.